# create JPA query that will filter results by certain condition

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa

I have a project with @ManyToMany mapping between 2 entities and I would like to select filtered attribute of an object that resist inside the first object.
My JSON will explain it better:  `"name": "my first campaign", "bid": 30, "startDate": "2023-07-22T00:00:00.000+00:00", "products": [ {"productId": 4, "title": "ovJSOVx", "category": "clothes", "price": 27, "serialNumber": "yW2dFn7fwu"}]`

Basically I have an object (campaign) that contains another object (products) and what I would like to do is to filter the query results by category(which resist inside of products)
Is there a way to achieve this using sql or should I do it using java?

this is the combined sql table that was created using jpa because of the @ManyToMany mapping: `CAMPAIGN_ID      PRODUCT_ID   1   1 1   2 1   4 2   1 2   2 2   4 3   1 3   2 3   4`